# POST nested object with querystring

Tags: json, node.js, http, npm, query-string

i've tried to POST a nested object but it seems querystring can't deal with it.
Nested fields aren't stringified at all and these fields are replaced by an empty string.

A sample code :

```
var data = querystring.stringify(
{
   l: ["test.com", "test.com"],
   t: {d: {c: 0}, i: {c: 0}},
   p: {c: 0},
   f: {c: 0},
   c: {c: 0}
} );
var query = new Query( data.length );

var request = http.request( query );
request.write( data );
request.end();
```

How can I handle that (with querystring or another module) ?

Thank you

Comment: Why are trying to pass an object using query params instead of body?

Answer (score 0):

I finally used request module (npm install request), this is very simple to use and the data serialization is done by the module !